# Converting a type to its nullable equivalent

Tags: c#, type-conversion, nullable

I have this bit of code

```
 NullableConverter nullableConverter = new NullableConverter(type);
 Type baseType = nullableConverter.UnderlyingType;
 Object value = Convert.ChangeType(rule.Data, baseType);
 constant = Expression.Constant(value);
```

In this case type is `decimal?` but it could be any nullable type.

I need `value` to be of type `decimal?`, not type `decimal` as it currently is.  The problem, is that `Convert.ChangeType` doesn't work properly with nullable types.  So I'm creating a non-nullable first.

How can I convert the string contained in `rule.Data` to `type`?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Are you asking how to convert a `string` to a `decimal?` ?

Comment: Could you remove the vars? This would make the types involved more obvious.

Comment: I don't know the type, it's all generic, none of the vars (which I changed) will help.  In this case, `type` happened to be `decimal?`, `rule.Data` is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

When a nullable struct is boxed in an `Object` it doesn't store a boxed nullable struct.  If the struct doesn't have a value it will just box `null`, and if it has a value it will box the underlying value of the nullable struct.

You would need to not be boxing it for this to even be possible.

Comment: I don't need to store it as an object, I need to get `rule.Data` converted to `type` (which is a Nullable<> type).  I don't much care how I manage it.

Comment: @CaffGeek Well, you're passing it to `Expression.Constant`, which takes an object, so no matter what you do it will be boxed at that point.

Comment: appears my issue is something else.  You're right, even if it is a `decimal?` my code still fails later with the same error as when it's a `decimal`